# Problems with multipass VM after upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, multipass

I have just updated multipass to 1.12 on MacOS on my M2 macpro. And now my instances are in an unknown state.
The local driver is qemu and these are the latest logs after a reboot and `multipass start --all`

```
[2023-06-27T09:06:20.349] [debug] [daemon] instance "wanted-tuatara" does not need to be recovered
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.663] [debug] [primary] process working dir ''
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.664] [info] [primary] process program 'qemu-system-aarch64'
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.664] [info] [primary] process arguments '-machine, virt,gic-version=3, -accel, hvf, -drive, file=/Library/Application Support/com.canonical.multipass/bin/../Resources/qemu/edk2-aarch64-code.fd,if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on, -cpu, host, -nic, vmnet-shared,model=virtio-net-pci,mac=52:54:00:74:31:e9, -device, virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi0, -drive, file=/var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/qemu/vault/instances/primary/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-arm64.img,if=none,format=qcow2,discard=unmap,id=hda, -device, scsi-hd,drive=hda,bus=scsi0.0, -smp, 1, -m, 1024M, -qmp, stdio, -chardev, null,id=char0, -serial, chardev:char0, -nographic, -cdrom, /var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/qemu/vault/instances/primary/cloud-init-config.iso'
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.670] [debug] [qemu-system-aarch64] [22687] started: qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -nographic -dump-vmstate /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/multipassd.QOvGIv
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.729] [info] [primary] process state changed to Starting
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.731] [info] [primary] process state changed to Running
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.731] [debug] [qemu-system-aarch64] [22688] started: qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt,gic-version=3 -accel hvf -drive file=/Library/Application Support/com.canonical.multipass/bin/../Resources/qemu/edk2-aarch64-code.fd,if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on -cpu host -nic vmnet-shared,model=virtio-net-pci,mac=52:54:00:74:31:e9 -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi0 -drive file=/var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/qemu/vault/instances/primary/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-arm64.img,if=none,format=qcow2,discard=unmap,id=hda -device scsi-hd,drive=hda,bus=scsi0.0 -smp 1 -m 1024M -qmp stdio -chardev null,id=char0 -serial chardev:char0 -nographic -cdrom /var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/qemu/vault/instances/primary/cloud-init-config.iso
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.731] [info] [primary] process started
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.731] [warning] [daemon] Instance 'wanted-tuatara' is already running, but in an unknown state
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.731] [debug] [primary] Waiting for SSH to be up
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.731] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Waiting for SSH to be up
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.731] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:15:23.732] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:15:23.733] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:15:23.764] [debug] [primary] QMP: {"QMP": {"version": {"qemu": {"micro": 0, "minor": 0, "major": 8}, "package": ""}, "capabilities": ["oob"]}}

[2023-06-27T09:15:23.785] [debug] [primary] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:15:55.342] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:15:55.346] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:15:55.347] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:16:26.143] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:16:26.144] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:16:26.144] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:16:56.799] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:16:56.801] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:16:56.802] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:17:27.515] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:17:27.518] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:17:27.519] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:17:59.376] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:17:59.377] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:17:59.378] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:18:30.017] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:18:30.019] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:18:30.020] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:19:00.826] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:19:00.828] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:19:00.829] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:19:31.677] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:19:31.679] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:19:31.680] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:20:02.409] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] Resetting the network
[2023-06-27T09:20:02.411] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}

[2023-06-27T09:20:02.412] [debug] [wanted-tuatara] QMP: {"return": {}}
```

There's another similar issue here:
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/instance-primary-is-already-running-but-in-an-unknown-stateprimary-timed-out-waiting-for-response/33359

But it didn't get solved.

I don't really care about the VMs themselves, but the content of the disk in my home folder is important.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *MacOS isn't Ubuntu, Multipass is a Canonical product; why ask here?  If using Multipass on a Ubuntu system you'd be on-topic here*

Comment: I am running into the same issue and there seems nowhere a solution to be found on the internet only people with the same issue.